# What is the meaning of the following text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Would you please tell me what the meaning of the bold part is? Does "growth" refers to population? Then, how population growth can be due to population ageing?

> Only Sub-Saharan Africa and parts of India and South Asia are expected to see further rapid increases in population in the coming decades, **with the growth elsewhere mainly due to rapid population ageing.** [Source](https://books.google.nl/books?id=q1PwAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=google%20book%20%22to%20see%20further%20rapid%20increases%22&source=bl&ots=5X7Ly3ZU-U&sig=KWfHo9h6LaB3PQN6LYCCpFoLKsM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicpPiuuKjUAhWMCywKHfIoCX0Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=google%20book%20%22to%20see%20further%20rapid%20increases%22&f=false)

Comment: consider that *growth* can be negative.

Comment: @jim So, the text means in some countries, such as India, growth is positive and in other countries growth is negative?

Comment: It may be referring to population growth caused by a cohort of people reaching adulthood, and having children. Even if the overall fertility rate is going down (eg, having 2.5 children instead of 3.5), the fact that a lot of people are reaching their 20s soon and having children may mean that the overall population will keep going up for a while. Just guessing.

Comment: Actually population growth due to rapid population ageing makes no sense. Increased longevity (a lower death rate) may increase population over what might have been expected, but all the people getting old have already been born and aren't going to increase the population by getting older.

Comment: True, but lets say ten years ago the average lifespan was 60, and for every person that died a new person was born, you would have a stable population with no growth. If each year the average life span was increased by one year and the birth rate stayed the same you would slowly see an increase in the population.

Comment: It is poorly worded at best.

Comment: “Rapid population ageing” is a very odd way of wording it if you ask me. Time passes at the same speed for all of us, and nobody ages more rapidly than anyone else, including populations. “Rapid increase in average age” would be more natural to me.

Comment: @Xanne The increase in aging means that old people aren't dying as soon, which results in population growth.

Comment: @Barmar Read what I wrote.  See especially "increased longevity".

Comment: @Barmar: That is only one possible cause. It could also be caused by children dying at an alarming rate. You can't make any accurate statements about _expected lifespan_ by observing changes in _the average age of living citizens_. Correlation is not causation, nor is it an objectively measurable indication. Your set of people may have changed inbetween your two observations, and an average completely omits the **size** of the group you are calculating the average of.

Comment: @Flater Of course there can be other possible causes. I'm just explaining what the quoted statement is saying.

Comment: @Barmar: Population growth, expected lifespan, and the average age of living citizens are three completely different statistics that (at best) have a loose correlation. It is impossible to draw conclusions about one from observing a change in another. Which completely contradicts your statement that "The increase in aging means that old people aren't dying as soon, which results in population growth"

Comment: @Jim what is "negative growth"?  That appears self-contradictory to me.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Well, that would be shrinkage.  If the growth rate is negative then it’s getting smaller.

Comment: @Jim ah yes, I see what you mean.  That's growth used as "rate of change" or "amount of change" then isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

"Rapid population ageing" is a shorthand for an increase in the age distribution of the population.  In itself this cannot cause population growth.  It is necessary (mathematically) that the crude death rate (CDR) be below the crude birth rate (CBR).  The CDR is deaths per one thousand people per year (as it is usually expressed), and CBR is live births per thousand per year.

Consider the extreme example where the CBR is zero.  The fact that the living folks age, and on average are older, does not increase the population.  In fact you could imagine an indefinite increase in longevity without any increase in population if you had no live births (and no net migration).

In developed countries at the present time, the CDR is below the CBR.  Given the age distribution of the population and a CBR below replacement, *eventually* the population is going to decline.  Also, the CDR will increase even though people live longer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term **'population ageing'** refers to people living longer. The net result in these countries is that the population continues to grow although at a slower rate.

Comment: In every context I've seen it; it means the _[implicitly increasing] average age of citizens_.

Comment: @Flater Aren't these the same thing? 'People living longer' **must** be referring to 'people living longer on average' to make any sense here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: They are related of course, but used in different contexts. Similarly, mass and weight are related but do not express the exact same thing.  You often see population ageing mentioned in relation to how a shrinking ratio of adult workforce is not capable of sustaining the social welfare of a growing ratio of senior citizens. Which is what we're starting to deal with because of the baby boomers now (who will be reaching retirement age in a few years). Population ageing can also occur because of **less children per adult**, not just longer lifespans for seniors.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I also missed this in my initial reply: "the average lifespan" and "the average age of a country's citizens" are by no means expressing the same thing. The latter expresses the _distribution of citizens among age groups_, which is something different. It does not care about the expected lifespan of people, it only expresses the current distribution. Just because they _can_ be caused by the same thing does not mean that they are the same thing.

Comment: @Flater Note that OP says 'the term _population ageing_ **refers to** people living longer' (bolding mine). Not 'is strictly defined as'. As a paraphrase, it's fine.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: But it doesn't refer to it. People living longer is _one of the possible causes_, which is not the same as what it refers to. Otherwise, population ageing also refers to a surge in child death. "Traffic accidents" does not refer to drunk driving (but drunk driving is one of many causes of traffic accidents), death does not refer to ingesting choking hazards (but again, it can be a cause), a bad mood does not refer to a lack of sleep (again, it can be a cause). Regardless of how loose you intend the definition to be, it's still not correct.

Comment: @Flater Add up all the ages of the population and divide by the size of the population. If the answer is larger than that you got the year before, (1) the average age has increased; (2) on average, people are living longer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Calculate the average. Kill a million children. Calculate the average again. If anything, people live less long on average (due to getting killed), yet the average age _of currently living people_ increased.

Comment: You're not accepting that meaningfully, comparable statistics have to refer to collection at the same point in time. The day after the killing, people are living longer on average again than the day before. Essentially, 'living longer' is here being restricted to those now living, just like 'average age'.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier in the same paragraph of the source document, the author phrases it more explicitly (the emphasis is mine):

> The number of people and where they live is changing rapidly. The world's population has doubled over the past forty years, but the **pace of growth** is **slowing**...

The author is almost certainly referring back to the decreasing growth rate. The entire paragraph is phrased a little awkwardly, but the sentence you call out in your question would benefit from a modifier before the word **growth**, e.g., **reduced**, **slower**, **decreasing**.